# Persisting custom class object to user defaults

Tags: swift

I am trying to use NSCoding to encode a custom object to user defaults.

I instantiate an instance of the "league" object, and then attempt to save it to defaults, and decode and retrieve it in another area. When retrieving the decoded object from user defaults, only the "top level" of the object is recovered (the team list which is just the names of the teams and the name of the league) and the inherited parameters below the league have no data (i.e., the roster or the team that has an array of players and those players names).

The classes are defined below. The class structures interact properly within a single instance of the app, but it's not keeping all parameters of the league object together in user defaults.

Where am I messing this up?

```
class player: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var first = ""
    var last = ""
    var parent1 = ""
    var parent2 = ""
    var position = ""
    var shoots = ""
    var goals = 0
    var assists = 0
    var points = 0

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(first, forKey: "first")
        aCoder.encode(last, forKey: "last")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let first = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "first")
        let last = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "last")
        self.init(first: first as! String, last: last as! String)
    }

    init(first: String, last: String) {
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    }
}

class team: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var roster: [player] = []
    var gameList: [game] = []
    var name: String = ""

    init(name: String, roster: [player]) {
        self.roster = roster
        // self.gameList = gameList
        self.name = name
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(roster, forKey: "roster")
        //aCoder.encode(gameList, forKey: "gameList")
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")

    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let roster = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "roster") as! [player]
        //self.gameList = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "gameList") as! [game]
        let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        self.init(name: name, roster: roster)
    }    
}

class game: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var datePlayed = 0.0
    var graphLabel = ""
    var shotsFor = 0
    var shotsAgainst = 0
    var goalsFor = 0
    var goalsAgainst = 0
    var opponent = ""
    var location = ""
    var goalie1Time = 0
    var goalie1Shots = 0
    var goalie1Goals = 0
    var goalie2Time = 0
    var goalie2Shots = 0
    var goalie2Goals = 0

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(datePlayed, forKey: "datePlayed")
        aCoder.encode(opponent, forKey: "opponent")
        aCoder.encode(shotsFor, forKey: "shotsFor")

    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let datePlayed = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "datePlayed")
        let opponent = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "opponent")
        let shotsFor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "shotsFor")

        self.init(datePlayed: datePlayed as! Double, opponent: opponent as! String, shotsFor: shotsFor as! Int)
    }

    init(datePlayed: Double, opponent: String, shotsFor: Int) {
        self.datePlayed = datePlayed
        self.opponent = opponent
        self.shotsFor = shotsFor
    }
}

class league: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var teamList = [team]()
    var name = String()
    var currentTeam = team(name: "", roster: [])

    init(teamList: [team], name: String) {
        self.teamList = teamList
        self.name = name
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let teamList = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "teamList")
        let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name")
        self.init(teamList: teamList as! [team], name: name as! String)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(teamList, forKey: "teamList")
    }
}
```

In another file, I instantiate a league object and then attempt to save to user defaults with the following:

```
let newTeam = team(name: newTeamNameInput.text!, roster: [])
newTeam.name = newTeamNameInput.text!
variables.currentLeague.teamList.append(newTeam)
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: variables.currentLeague)
userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "league")
userDefaults.synchronize()
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and then attempt to retrieve it with the following:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "league") != nil{
    let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "league") as! Data
    variables.currentLeague = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded ) as! league
} else {
    print("league does not exist")
}
```

Comment: 1. Class names should start with uppercase letters. 2. You need the `init(coder:)` and `encode(with:)` method in all of your `NSCoding` classes, not just `league`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the note on class syntax.  Sorry, I should have mentioned that I do have init(coder:) and encode(with:) in all the classes, I missed them when pasting them here. Can you say if it's possible to just save the entire object or do you have to save each custom value separately.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to archive the top level object. As long as its `encode(with:)` method encodes its properties (and recursively, those classes properly encode their properties), it should all work. Since you didn't post all relevant code, no one can help you verify it is all OK.

Comment: thanks again, I just updated the post above with all the code.